# How to implement a slide in/out menu on only a part of the viewcontroller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to implement a slide menu as indicated in the picture bellow. Basically after the user presses a button, I want to create an animation that slides the label and the image (1) to the right then slides the two images (2) in.

[image]

I have so far managed to slide the label and image (1) to the right using:

```
self.mylabel.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
self.myimage.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
```

But can't find a solution to bring the view #2 in ...

I am not looking for specific code (Although that would be nice :) but rather someone who could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So, first I would put your label and image inside their own UIView to make manipulating them easier (though I don't know the rest of your UI so maybe that's not a good idea).

I think your problem might not be how to slide them (as you say, you've already worked out how to slide things about);

```
self.mylabel2.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
self.myimage2.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
```

will do it.

Is your problem how to position them off screen in the first place?

If you want them to end up in the same place as the initial label and image you can use their starting position as a guide.

In your `viewDidLoad` do this

```
self.mylabel2.center.x = self.mylabel2.center.x - self.view.bounds.width
self.myimage2.center.x = self.myimage2.center.x - self.view.bounds.width
```

This will position them one screen width to the left of the original label and image.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer ! I have tried using `self.mylabel2.center.x = self.mylabel2.center.x - self.view.bounds.width` in `viewDidLoad` but the label is not being taken off screen ... Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? If so, you should set up a horizontal constraint, set it up as an outlet,  then animate changing the constant value on the constraint. If you google it you should find examples of animating using constraints.